# Django: How to set initial values for a field in an inline model formset?

Tags: python, django, default-value, django-forms

I have what I think should be a simple problem.  I have an inline model formset, and I'd like to make a select field have a default selected value of the currently logged in user.  In the view, I'm using Django's Authentication middleware, so getting the user is a simple matter of accessing `request.user`.

What I haven't been able to figure out, though, is how to set that user as the default selected value in a select box (ModelChoiceField) containing a list of users.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

This does the trick. It works by setting the initial values of all "extra" forms.

```
formset = MyFormset(instance=myinstance)
user = request.user
for form in formset.forms:
    if 'user' not in form.initial:
        form.initial['user'] = user.pk
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how to handle this in inline formsets, but the following approach will work for normal Forms and ModelForms:

You can't set this as part of the model definition, but you can set it during the form initialization:

```
def __init__(self, logged_in_user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['my_user_field'].initial = logged_in_user

...

form = MyForm(request.user)
```

Comment: Not sure how this would work with the inline formset.  I'm using inlineformset_factory to create my formset and passing it the form class, not an instance.  So I'm not directly instantiating a form object anywhere and don't know how I'd pass it that constructor parameter.

Comment: Hmmm... I believe ModelForms will take the 'default' value, won't they?  And standard form fields use initial as you show, but as far as I know there's no reason to go super() on it.

Comment: This is great! I was looking for a way to send data from the form to the view so that I can send status that will be displayed using the messages framework. In the form I used the initial keyword, and then in the view I did this on validate: 

            cur_key_status = form.cleaned_data['key_status']
            messages.success(request, cur_key_status)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rune Kaagaard's idea above, except I noticed that formsets provide an extra_forms property: [django.forms.formsets code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/forms/formsets/)

```
@property
def extra_forms(self):
    """Return a list of all the extra forms in this formset."""
    return self.forms[self.initial_form_count():]
```

So, sticking with the example above:

```
formset = MyFormset(instance=myinstance)
user = request.user
for form in formset.extra_forms:
    form.initial['user'] = user.pk
```

Saves having to test any initial forms, just provide default for extra forms.